# Button to make boxes and add the counted numbers inside

Tags: javascript, html, dom, counter

I'm having trouble starting. I'm trying to make an 'add box' button that will add a new box to a container each time it is clicked.  But I also need the number displayed inside of the box. For instance when I click it once, a box shows up as 1 and then the second box shows 2 etc. I'm not sure how to combine them in js.

Comment: Please include the code you've tried so far

Answer (score 0):

To start with. Try this demo.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/tryit.asp?filename=tryjsref_onclick

Here a code is available which make add Hello World Text. Alter the code to create a box instead.

Comment: How is this answering OP's question?

Answer (score 0):

Since you didn't include any code, I can only guess. But I think you mean something like this:

```js
var boxes = 1;
var addBox = function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("boxes")[0].innerHTML += "<div>Box " + boxes + "</div>";
    boxes++;
};

window.addEventListener("load", function(){
    document.getElementsByClassName("addBox")[0].addEventListener("click", addBox);
});
```

```html
<button class="addBox">Add Box</button>

<hr>

<div class="boxes"></div>
```

---

This code is just a quick-and-dirty example of how it could be done. 
I'm basically just creating a counter variable and increment it on every execution of the `addBox()` function.